# Is it possible to implement Spring Model/Controllers with a PHP View?

Tags: php, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a simple 'hello world' working example where I have a Spring Web Service, on an Apache Tomcat server. I have this behind a firewall, and then in my DMZ I have an Apache HTTP Server, where I consume the Spring Web Service using PHP.

As a hello world this works. I want to move to the next step and implement a CRUD, connecting to a MySQL server also inside the network, and I want to do this with a proper MVC architecture.

Would I be right in saying my view would always be the PHP/HTML on the Apache HTTP Server, while my controllers and models would be implemented on the Tomcat which would effectively be my Application Server? What would provide the connectivity to the database, the controller or the model?

My reasoning for doing the actual view in PHP as opposed to Java is to use the skills of the small team of programmers I have available. I want the PHP guys to concentrate on the look and GUI of the site, while the Java/Spring side would concentrate on business logic, but I am struggling a little with where each part goes when you implement MVC on a 3-tier architecture.

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can use PHP as the template engine for generating views using Spring MVC.  You can use [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com), a Java implementation of PHP (supports PHP 5) and create a Spring MVC `View` implementation out of it.  Then, the `View` implementation can be used to parse PHP scripts just like any other view technology supported by Spring MVC (such as JSP, JSTL, FreeMarker, Velocity, etc.).  See my [sample app](http://spring-mvc-enum.appspot.com/php) for a page generated using a PHP template and Spring MVC.  The source code is linked from the sample.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you only need one backend language. Both PHP and Java are backend languages so you'll have to choose one between them. If your business logic is already written on Java, you only need to use HTML for achieving your goal. You would need PHP only if you want to abandon Java for your business logic purposes.

Comment: How would pure HTML on an Apache HTTP Server in a DMZ consume a web service provided by a separate server Apache Tomcat?

Comment: In that case... through an API created with servlets. A bit of AJAX and voìla!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you mean that the actual bit of dynamic code on the Apache Web server consuming the service from the application server would be JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Something I don't understand, PHP and Java both are backend languages, why do you need both of them together.. Ideally you must choose one. Also, such a complex infrastructure is difficult to maintain. It's always better to implement clean stuff now rather then regret. I would suggest to select one backend language.

Comment: The PHP would be simply consuming web services. Isn't this necessary in any 3-tier architecture? I could have another Tomcat for the View, but they would still be separate servers physically and there would be separate Java projects on both. Once they are separate and communicating via web services, why are they bound to a single programming language?

Comment: What do you mean by having another tomcat for the View? And no this is not a 3 tier architecture, this is redundancy.... If you can simply consume the webservice via the spring webapp, why do you require PHP, simply create your JSP/HTML pages and directly put them in your webapp. This avoids one more server, one backend language, less complications for overall structure, less Spring-Security based problems(That guy is nasty for such stuff).